# Barcode line overlay scanner

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

I'm using this package [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner) in my flutter application, and it works fine, it opens the camera in full screen and scans QR/Barcode in any place on the screen.
I want to add a specific detection area [line for barcode, secure for QR] on the screen with a camera full view.
how can I achieve this

Comment: I think it is work in progress, check [this PR](https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/pull/176).

Answer (score 0):

By observing the documentation of the package, I have found no properties to customize the Scan Screen but there is a package called [flutter_barcode_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner) that provides the required UI out of the box.

[image]

Also here is a gallery of [QR Code / Bar Code packages](https://fluttergems.dev/qr-code-bar-code/) provided by [fluttergems.dev](https://fluttergems.dev/)